# VHDL, passing a partial array of std_logic_vector into an instantiated port map

Tags: vhdl

Consider the following code

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package pkg is
    type foo is (A, B, C);
    type foo_vector is array (foo) of std_logic_vector;
end package;
```

Where an entity has the following ports

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity baz is 
port (iInput : in foo_vector;
      oOutput : out foo_vector);
end;
```

And it is instantiated by a top module. Now the question is how can i pass only part of the std_logic_vectors of bar into baz instance? Compilation fails when i attempt to use (open)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity top is 
end;

architecture rtl of top is 
    signal bar: foo_vector (open) (31 downto 0) := (others => (others => '0'));
begin
    inst : entity work.baz 
    port map (iInput => bar(open)(3 downto 0), --The (open) here does not work
              oOutput => open);    
end;
```

Comment: Discounting that the reserved word **open** stands neither for a subtype indication nor a discrete range. you need either an intermediary signal or implicit signal (6.5.6.3 Port clauses) for an actual  that is an expression (where supported, likely not in synthesis). The expression assigned to intermediary or implicit signal would be an array aggregate (9.3.3.3 Array aggregates) who's type is determined by context (9.3.3.1 General) excluding the aggregate itself (declare a subtype used in a qualified expression or constrain the port formal). (you should really show error messages).

Comment: A object cannot be declared without all ranges constrained. Similarly, no ports on an entity can be left unconstrained when it is instantiated. So the signal and entity instantiations error because they have unconstrained ranges.

Comment: @Tricky not true. VHDL-2008 allows this way to declare the signal. That's because the first range is already constrained in the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making your life quite difficult using jagged arrays with unconstrained types that you want to partially assign. I would say: keep it simple. Just use three seperate arrays `foovec_A`, `foovec_B`, and `foovec_C`.

But if you really want it your way, you will need to add logic to send the required signals to a seperate `foo_vector`. E.g.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package pkg is
    type foo is (A, B, C);
    type foo_vector is array (foo) of std_logic_vector;
end package;

use work.pkg.all;

entity baz is 
port (iInput : in foo_vector;
      oOutput : out foo_vector);
end;

architecture rtl of baz is begin
end architecture;

entity top is 
end;

library ieee;

architecture rtl of top is 
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use work.pkg.all;
    signal bar: foo_vector(open)(31 downto 0) := (others => (others => '0'));
    signal bar_part: foo_vector(open)(3 downto 0);
    signal output : foo_vector(open)(0 downto 0);
begin
    conn : for i in foo generate
        bar_part(i) <= bar(i)(3 downto 0);
    end generate;

    inst : entity work.baz 
    port map (iInput => bar_part,
              oOutput => output);    
end;
```

will compile (VHDL-2008 mode).

Comment: This answer is fair